# Prove $n^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{n}+1) \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}$

Tags: inequality

> if $x_i$ is positive real number that $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i=1$,Prove:$$n^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{n}+1) \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}$$
>   Additional info:I'm looking for solutions and hint that using Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM and Holder because I have background in them.

*Things I have done:* using Holder inequality $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{n}+1) \ge (x_1x_2..x_n+1)^n=2^n$$$$n^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{n}+1) \ge (x_1x_2..x_n+1)^n=(2n)^n$$

Now I should Prove $$(2n)^n\ge\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}$$

And I stuck here.

Comment: The last line is not true, since the $x_i$ can become arbitrarily large/small. (Take $x_1=(2n)^n$ and $x_2=\frac 1{x_1}$.)

Comment: @Ragnar,you are right,I think starting with holder is not good,any other method to start?

Comment: You can make it homogeneous by multiplying with $\prod x_i$ at the right places.

Comment: A certain similarity with Dospinescu inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $n=1$ is trivial, so suppose $n \ge 2$.

Since $\prod_i x_i = 1$, 
$$n^n \prod_{i=1}^n (x_i^n + 1) = \prod_{i=1}^n (n x_i^{n/2} + n x_i^{-n/2}) $$
Now $n x^{n/2} + n x^{-n/2} \ge x + 1/x \ge 2$.  If all $t_i \ge 2$, show that
$\sum_i t_i \le \prod_i t_i$  (easy when all $t_i = 2$, and derivative of right side wrt $t_i$ is greater than derivative of left).

Answer (score 0):

> $$n^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{n}+1) \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}$$

Let $x_1=a_1/a_2,x_2=a_2/a_3\cdots$

Then $$(x_i^{n}+1)=\frac{(a_1^{n}+a_2^n)}{a_2^n}$$
So $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^{n}+1)=\frac{(a_1^{n}+a_2^n)}{a_2^n}.\frac{(a_2^{n}+a_3^n)}{a_3^n}\cdots\frac{(a_n^{n}+a_1^n)}{a_1^n}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{a_1}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}=\frac{a_2}{a_1}+\frac{a_3}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{a_n}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i}=\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2}{a_1a_2}+\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2}{a_1a_2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n^2+a_1^2}{a_na_1}$$
See if this simplifies your problem.